# remove comma and semicolon from webelement list

Tags: java, selenium, collections, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

```
public List<String> pageLabelApp() {     
    List<WebElement> lableList = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("#Factors label"));
    List<String> labelOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement temp : lableList) {
        labelOne.add(temp.getText());
    }

    System.out.println("Labels:" + labelOne);

    return labelOne;
}
```

Output:

```
Labels:[Rate:, , , Method:, , ]
```

I'm new to web automation and using selenium + jbehave

From the above output i need to eliminate comma's and colons, can someone help me on this?

My expected output is

```
Labels:[Rate, Method]
```

Answer (score 3):

Talking about **commas**, they are in output because you have added empty strings to a list. You can avoid this by checking for empty string using `isEmpty()` method:

```
for (WebElement temp : lableList) {
    String text = temp.getText().trim(); // trim() removes leading and trailing whitespaces

    if (!str.isEmpty())
    {
        labelOne.add(text); 
    }
}
```

What about **semicolons** (if only semicolons bother you), you can easily use `.replaceAll()` method:

```
for (WebElement temp : lableList) {
    String text = temp.getText().trim().replaceAll(":", "");

    if (!str.isEmpty())
    {
        labelOne.add(text); 
    }
}
```

If there are many types of symbols which you want to remove or if, for example, you want to remove semicolons only in the end of string, then you should use regular expressions.